# Silverlight deployment on networks with high restrictions

Tags: silverlight

I have a situation where a product I am developing requires Silverlight 5.x and the target audience includes users on remote sites. The users are of varying experience but for the most part it is assumed that they have rudimentary skills. With that in mind the network that they connect through prohibits any sort of download. Is there an easy deployment model for Silverlight on networks with high levels of restriction?

Comment: If there is no downloading, how do they view images on the web?

Comment: You have their IT support personal install Silverlight on all the machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With that in mind the network that they connect through prohibits any sort of download.

In that case you're going to have to provide the Silverlight installer yourself.

There is a [Silverlight forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/38534.aspx/1) on this topic that offers a workaround. It involves downloading the installation executable (from here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/38534.aspx/1) and then manually installing it on the machines.

There is also a link to a [deployment guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/8/d/78da8ec9-8801-42e5-89e5-3809386f1316/Silverlight%20Deployment%20Guide.doc) (Word document) which goes into great detail on how to install Silverlight in various ways - including manually.

However, it would probably be far simpler to get the company to relax the "no download" rule for the Silverlight runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If their IT team is powerful enough to block downloads from AD, they can push it with WSUS. Silverlight can be pushed through WSUS, easiest way to get it on all your PCs.